# npm can't install quick.db even it's dependencies are present

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, npm-install, quick.db

I have quick.db's dependencies and I can't still install it. I got Python 2.x and Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. I don't know why it won't let me install quick.db... Can anybody help me to fix it?

Here's the log:

```
PS C:\Users\scott\Documents\SCOTTDEVELOP> npm install quick.db
 
> integer@3.0.1 install C:\Users\scott\Documents\SCOTTDEVELOP\node_modules\integer
> prebuild-install || npm run build-release
 
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=12.16.1 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
 
> integer@3.0.1 build-release C:\Users\scott\Documents\SCOTTDEVELOP\node_modules\integer
> node-gyp rebuild --release
 
 
C:\Users\scott\Documents\SCOTTDEVELOP\node_modules\integer>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  integer.cpp
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
..\src\integer.cpp(370): warning C4804: '-': unsafe use of type 'bool' in operation [C:\Users\scott\Documents\SCOTTDEVE
LOP\node_modules\integer\build\integer.vcxproj]
C:\\Users\\scott\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\12.16.1\\x64\\node.lib : fatal error LNK1106: invalid file or disk f
ull: cannot seek to 0x2FC71E [C:\Users\scott\Documents\SCOTTDEVELOP\node_modules\integer\build\integer.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\scott\Documents\SCOTTDEVELOP\node_modules\integer
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! integer@3.0.1 build-release: `node-gyp rebuild --release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the integer@3.0.1 build-release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\scott\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-10T01_18_07_632Z-debug.log
npm WARN edinburgh@1.0.0 No repository field.
 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! integer@3.0.1 install: `prebuild-install || npm run build-release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the integer@3.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\scott\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-10T01_18_08_872Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to install quick.db.
I just installed the latest version of node.js.